# RestFB: checkin with expanded link

Tags: facebook, restfb

I want to do the following:

To create a checking with a link. This code works:

```
FacebookType publishCheckinResponse = facebookClient.publish("me/checkins", FacebookType.class, 
                Parameter.with("message", "message"),
                Parameter.with("coordinates", coordinates),
                Parameter.with("link", "http://url"),
                Parameter.with("place", "placeId")
        );
```

But I need a link to have additional information, like icon and description.
This code produces empty icon and description.

When I post only link to "me/links", I can set these fields, and link looks exactly as I need.
Can somebody explain how to add "expanded" link to checking?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

`facebookClient.publish("me/links", String.class,
                inputStream, Parameter.with("access_token", accessToken),
                Parameter.with("message", msgTxtOption),
                Parameter.with("picture", imageURL),
                Parameter.with("link", link == null ? "" : link),
                Parameter.with("description", Description),
                Parameter.with("name", titile));`

-Rohit